Improper integral $dx/((x^2+1)(x^2+4))$ using Analytic function
Problem: solve
$$
\int_{- \infty}^{\infty} \frac{dx}{(x^2+1)(x^2+4)}
$$
using analytic functions.\
My solution technique is try to rewrite the problem as the following, find the singular points and then use Cauchy's integral theorem
$$
\int_{- \infty}^{\infty} \frac{dx}{(x^2+1)(x^2+4)} = 2 \int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{dx}{(x^2+1)(x^2+4)} = 2 \int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{dz}{(z^2+1)(z^2+4)}
$$
where $z= \pm i$ and $z= \pm 2i$. However this does not really help me and any suggestion is highly appreciated. The solution should equal $\pi /6$. Thanks.
Sincerely, TS

You do not really need complex numbers here. Perform partial fraction decomposition and you will obtain two integrals that lead to arctangent functions (which are analytic on the real line)

what is $\frac{1/3}{x^2 +1}   -  \frac{1/3}{x^2 +4}$

Thanks for input, I've solved it now using the contour method.

so I separated the fraction to yield
$\frac{1}{(x^2+1)(x^2+4)} = \frac{1}{3(x^2+1)} - \frac{1}{3(x^2+4)}$
If you integrate them separately, you should get something like this
$\frac{2}{3}\int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{dx}{x^2+1} -\frac{2}{3}\int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{dx}{x^2+4}$
After further computation, you should see that the answer is indeed $\frac{\pi}{6}$

Thank you. I just solved it with contour method.
